# Event propagation for custom javafx controls

Tags: java, javafx

I have created a custom control but I've noticed that (unlike default javafx controls) it does not propagate events to its parent.

In other words if I put the control in say a BorderPane, a MOUSE_MOVE event on the custom control can not be handled by anyone listening to the BorderPane.

Is there a default way to propagate events for custom controls?

Answer (score 0):

I also searched for a solution for that but i found nothing in the oracle docs.
The only thing i found is that all events could be fired through the static method

```
Event.fireEvent(EventTarget eventTarget,Event event)
```

where eventTarget specifies the path through which the event will travel (taken from java docs).
So maybe this helps

Comment: Every variation of static or non-static methods that result in a "re" fire of the original event seem to update the event in a way that the original context is gone. For example the target is updated so you don't know which control it actually originated from. IIRC this one overwrites the target as well unless you have a different experience?

Comment: I haven't regognized that. Am i right that your custom control doesn't extend from node, scene or window?

Comment: It extends javafx.scene.control.Control

Comment: In my case it works. Maybe you could post some code.